# ¿Como sería un mantenimiento a la base de datos?

Tags: mysql

Buenas hace tiempo desarrolle un sistema web, en `PHP` con gestor de base de datos `Mysql` y dentro de la documentación a entregar para el sistema, me solicita un proceso o procedimientos para darle mantenimiento a la base de datos o al sistema, solo que no sé como crear el mantenimiento a la bd no comprendo bien a que se refiere.

Comment: Con el pasar del tiempo la base de datos se hace mas pesada y las operaciones sobre la misma, mas lentas. Tambien si es un sistema con mucho borrado de filas, se puede producer fragmentacion de los indices...tambien las estadisticas pueden no estar actualizadas. Plan de mantenimiento, yo incluiria una estrategia de particionamiento o bien una estrategia de respaldos incrementales y asi solo mantener la informacion mas reciente, digamos de los ultimos 4 anios....

Comment: ...tambien un job o algo que se encargue de actualizar las estadisticas de la bd, y otro job que de acuerdo al % de fragmentacion de un indice reorganize o reconstruya los mismos. Y ademas debieses proveer un archive de configuracion de MySQL que sea optimo para el servidor destino...no sea que instalen la base de datos en un servidor poderoso pero que use la configuracion por defecto de MySQL....

Comment: @Hackerman entonces, se puede decir que con los respaldos de la base de datos, es dejar digamos lo actual y por medio de respaldos quitar lo anterior y que solo se quede lo actual

Comment: Si, respaldos historicos....tambien es una practica general el mantener tus ddl scripts en un sistema de versionado, de esa forma tambien tienes la forma de darle un seguimiento a los cambios que ha sufrido el schema de la base de datos...de todas maneras, trata de hacer algo que sea lo mas completo posible!